# Vertex Port Labelling in Java JUNG

Tags: java, graph, label, jung

it is my first post.
I am trying to implement a graph searching algorithm, which needs all vertex ports to be labelled. What I mean is, suppose you are in a vertex. All routes leading from vertex have to be labelled.

The numbering of ports is completely arbitrary. Can you please give me any tips on how to accomplish something like this? I can't seem to find port object in Jung. Thanks for your help.

Comment: JUNG does not provide native support for vertex ports.

Generally speaking, however, graph search doesn't use this concept.  Can you say more about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. What I am implementing is in fact algorithm, in which one traversing agent needs to create a map of a graph. The algorithm assumes model, in which  all ports of graph are labelled.

Comment: Does this algorithm assume that the vertices all have the same degree?  In any event, your vertex class can be anything you want, including something that has built in storage for labels for ports.  Or you can store that information in an auxiliary data structure.

Comment: No, the degree is completely arbitrary. Thank you for your tips, I wll try to figure something out : )